# Please show that $f(\beta_0,\beta_1)=\log(1+\operatorname{exp}(-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)))+\log(1+\operatorname{exp}(-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)))$

Tags: statistics, regression, operations-research, logistic-regression

I would like to show that the following result is indeed true. I am very new with this subject, so I ask for a hint to get me started please.

> Please show that $f(\beta_0,\beta_1)=\log(1+\operatorname{exp}(-y_1(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_1)))+\log(1+\operatorname{exp}(-y_2(\beta_0+\beta_1 x_2)))$

where $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ are any given data and is convex in $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$

The formula for the logistic regression is given as $$\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\beta_2 x= \log \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)$$, where $p$ is the probability. I know that I can check if something is indeed convex being looking at the Hessian matrix.

I recognize that $\frac{p}{1-p}$ is the odds is this is helpful?

The "action" of $f$ is not defined either I don't think, so I'm not sure how to start simplifying the left hand side.

Very vague... I'm not sure what it is a probability of? Hoping someone is familiar with "logistic regression"

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what tag would be good other than what I already have? thanks

Comment: Statistics seems to fit, but your question appears to lack a clear problem statement. "Proving result..." what result is to be proved?

Comment: What is your reaction to my answer below? If you think it is correct, please accept and upvote it. If you think it is wrong, please point out the error.

Answer (score 1):

Proof for $f(\beta_0,\beta_1)$ being convex with respect to $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$:

1) $g(x)$ is convex $\Longleftrightarrow  g(a^Tu)$ is convex with respect to $u$ for column matrices $a$ and $u$.

2) Sum of convex functions is convex.

3) $\ln(1+e^x)$ is convex.

Let $g(x) = \ln(1+e^x)$ in 1). Let $a_i=-[y_i\ x_iy_i]^T$. $f(\beta_0,\beta_1)$ is then the sum of convex functions $g(a_i^Tu)$ where $u=[\beta_0\ \beta_1]^T$ which is then convex which is the desired result.